# Django - admin questions

Tags: python, django, admin

I know that similar questions have been asked here in stackoverflow, but this is not just a mere question but a confirmation of my basic understanding. This is directed to those who have knowledge in Django.

My dilemma is the function `admin.site.register()` in admin.py in Django. My undestanding is that it accepts a number of arguments; I am playing around with it at this moment by working on the tutorials provided at the Django website. The arguments that I have at this time are Questions(model), QuestionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

and i have this `admin.site.register(Question,QuestionAdmin)`.

the QuestionAdmin class changes the outlook of the Question Page in admin. it allows me to add, reduce the number of information that I want to be shown at the same time, edit how it looks.

However, when I tried this `admin.site.register(Questions,Choice)` where Choice is a model. it spits out an error.

Does this mean that admin.site.register accepts arguments:

a  The Model you want to add/register
 b)  any classes specifically created to be of use to the model, such as functions, statements altering 
     the view and functionality of the model in display/view.

to add to that, when i increase the number of arguments to 3, it spits out an error saying that i have inputed 4.

is this function considering a nul value at the beginning?

Please do enlighten me O Wizards and Warlocks of Django.

Comment: side note QuestionsAdmin(class) should probably be QuestionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. You describe correctly what the second parameter is and what it does. So why do you then try to pass a model class? What are you hoping to achieve by doing so?

Comment: In terms of achieving something, it is just basically to confirm that what I understand about admin.site.register is accurate. It gives me relief that I am on the right path. Passing a model class was just to see what is happening and why it spits out an error, I was doing trial/error to understand what it means. Also, whenever an error occurs, lets say I have 3 arguments, the compilers says that I have 4. Does this function consider Nul as a value even though it is not coded?

Comment: No, that is standard Python behaviour, because the first parameter to a method call is always `self.`

Comment: Thanks Daniel Appreciate it, I am also new to python and I am learning it through web-development. It is something that I should take note of and remember. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For every `Model` (and `ModelAdmin`) you have, you should call `register` separately, for example:

```
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

The error about the 4 arguments is because `register` is a method of the default `AdminSite` instance, so the first argument is `self`. From the [django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L62):

```
def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
```

Comment: Ohh ok thank you for this, so basically every pair of Model-ModelAdmin is registered once and only once. Any additional Model or Model-ModelAdmin pair should be done as a new register.

I should take notes of the standard python behaviour, thanks

I used the word `pair` if thats ok with you since that For every model there is at least most one ModelAdmin.